# C++11: Move constructor is not triggered

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

Recently I have been studying the move semantics in C++11. I was so impressed that I could not wait to get my hands dirty and try them. The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    // default constructor produces a moderately sized array
    ArrayWrapper ()
        : _p_vals( new int[ 64 ] )
        , _size( 64 )
    {
        cout << "Default constructor: " << this << endl;
    }

    explicit ArrayWrapper (int n)
        : _p_vals( new int[ n ] )
        , _size( n )
    {
        cout << "Constructor: " << this << endl;
    }


    // move constructor
    ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)
        : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
            cout << "Move constructor: " << this << endl;
            other._p_vals = NULL;
            other._size = 0;
    }


    // copy constructor
    ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other)
        : _p_vals( new int[ other._size  ] )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
            cout << "Copy constructor: " << this << endl;
            for ( int i = 0; i < _size; ++i )
            {
                    _p_vals[ i ] = other._p_vals[ i ];
            }
    }
    ~ArrayWrapper ()
    {
            cout << "Destructor: " << this << endl;
            delete [] _p_vals;
    }

    void self () {
        cout << "This address: " << this << endl;
    }

public:
    int *_p_vals;
    int _size;
};

ArrayWrapper two() {
    ArrayWrapper a(7);
    cout << "Temp ArrayWrapper created!" << endl;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    ArrayWrapper b (two());
    b.self();
}
```

(I referenced some code from [1](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html))

The code may look long, but it is actually pretty naive, just a dump array.

On line 67, I deliberately created b with a rvalue and expected to see how the move constructor is called. But disappointingly, the output of this program is:

```
Constructor: 0x7fff51d60be0
Temp ArrayWrapper created!
This address: 0x7fff51d60be0
Destructor: 0x7fff51d60be0
```

The three addresses that are printed are the same and the move constructor is not called at all!
In fact, I later tried to delete the move constructor, and the program still compiled and gave the same output! And if you look a little carefully, you will find that the constructor is only called once, when constructing a. That is, when b is constructed, no constructor, neither move nor copy, is called at all!

I am really confused. Could anyone please tell me why the move constructor is not triggered, and how on earth b is constructed?

Comment: Copy elision...

Comment: @KerrekSB First time to hear that and googled it. Impressed and thank you! But do you know how to force the move constructor to be called?

Comment: `-fno-elide-constructors`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I have spent the whole night on this...

Comment: Just to be clear, copy elision is "better" than move and -fno-elide-constructors is useful here for educational purpose only.

Comment: A follow-up question: since two() function is return-by-value, what it should do is to make a copy of the local variable "a" before it vanishes, and return it, right? But how come the copy constructor is not called here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 5):

What you are experiencing is known as copy elision -- copy and move constructors can be skipped in certain contexts, even if skipping them would have observable side effects.  Common cases include RVO and NRVO (return value optimization and named RVO) or copy-initialization from an anonymous temporary.

To block it, explicitly call `std::move` at the point where you return from the function, and where you construct the value in `main`, as `std::move`'s rvalue cast makes elision illegal.  `std::move` takes a `T&` or `T&&` and turns it into a `T&&` in a way that prevents the "left hand side" from performing elision, as elision is restricted (at this point at least) to certain narrow cases.

It is generally a bad idea to block elision, but `std::move` will do it.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of RVO (Return Value Optimization) trick. 
Object from `ArrayWrapper two();` is created in place of `ArrayWrapper b;`.
That is why there is only one construction + destruction.

Try modifying it to something like:

```
ArrayWrapper two(bool disable_rvo) {
    ArrayWrapper a(7);
    cout << "Temp ArrayWrapper created!" << endl;
    if (disable_rvo) 
        return a;
    else
        return ArrayWrapper(8);
}

int main() {
    ArrayWrapper b (two(true));
    b.self();
}
```

And turn optimization off.